# What is "Stated-capital"?

Tags: accounting

What is **Stated Capital**? I have found some definitions on the Google, but I have not been able to comprehend it from this definitions. Could somebody explain it to me?

Comment: This question is a perfect fit for the Accounting site (currently a proposal in Area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting?referrer=FNOG9_mXNYnhlAdnl9FE8w2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stated Capital" is the *nominal* value (or "par" value) of all the outstanding shares of a company.

When a company issues shares each has a nominal price, say EUR $1.00$. But of course they may be sold for more (as far as I know, it is forbidden to issue a share and receive an amount less than its nominal value. Afterwards of course, the share of a company may be re-sold for less than its nominal value -but not when it is issued originally).

If it is sold for more, say EUR $1.50$, then the EUR $1.00$ is designated and presented as "Shareholder's Capital" in a specific line in the financial statements (usually the first line of Equity), while the "above par" value, the remaining EUR $0.50$, goes into another Equity line.